# ManagedUPnP: Discovery search URI without version?

Tags: c#, .net, upnp

For an application, I've to discover all "my" devices that runs, and their version, to push them an update(via another protocol).

But I can't figure out how to specify to the discovery object the URI it has to search, without having to specify the object.

**NOTE**: I know that I can also discover with null URI string and then filter on the device that I receive, but since I've a huge(600+) number of UPnP device on the network, but a small number of UPnP device that I need to search(~20), it will takes a lot of time, and I'm searching an efficient way of doing it.

So, if my URN is the following: `urn:upnp-org:device:TestDevice:2.2.5`, and I want to have 
`urn:upnp-org:device:TestDevice:*`, how should I proceed?

I tried

`urn:upnp-org:device:TestDevice:`
`urn:upnp-org:device:TestDevice:*`

Is there any wildcards? Placeholders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are misusing the versioning feature of `M-SEARCH`. `ST` version means **interface version, not implementation version** and higher versions are expected to be **fully backwards comaptible**. Hence you **are** capable of searching for **any version** of your device, by simply filling `ST:` with the lowest known version. **All devices will respond you, but with the version you searched for, not their actual version** (because they are backwards compatible). There is nothing like "wildcard", because devices are expected to do their best in matching the `M-SEARCH` requirement, not to be bragging about their actual version.

I suggest reading thoroughly the UPnP Device Architecture document, chapter 1.2.2 and 1.2.3 revolving around M-SEARCH request and response.

If you want to use UPnP for **implementation version** discovery (which is perfectly legal) i suggest implementing a custom service with a function returning that info. You already have a custom device, as i understand it.

Comment: Ok, I didn't know that. I took an existing code, which was using it as an implementation version. I will change that behavior.